# Select next and previous rows

Tags: postgresql, select

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
  id            bigint primary key,
  thread_id     bigint,
  is_notice     boolean,
  title         text,
  content       text
)
```

I display the list using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY is_notice desc, thread_id desc, id
```

Then, given the post selected by id(i.e. `SELECT * FROM post where id=3`), how do I retrieve the next and previous posts?

Comment: Well, not having a `WHERE` clause, you return all rows from the table, there is no next or previous.  Could you explain a bit better?

Comment: @dezso Sorry, I edited the post

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using PostgreSQL's [Window Functions](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9fd7a/14), specifically `LAG` and `LEAD`, should be able to show you the previous and next entries in your table.

```
select *
from (
    select  id, thread_id, is_notice, title, content,
            lag(id) over (order by is_notice desc, thread_id desc, id asc) as prev,
            lead(id) over (order by is_notice desc, thread_id desc, id asc) as next
    from post
    ) x
where 3 IN (id, prev, next);
```

A demo can be found here: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9fd7a/8

Comment: I wonder why you used `3 = ANY(array[id, prev, next])` and not the simpler `3 IN (id, prev, next)`

Comment: And shouldn't there be an `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER (...)`?

Comment: Right you are, I missed the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()` clause. I've edited accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I've edited `ORDER BY` clause to reflect my original intention.

Comment: @ypercube: You may be interested that `3 IN (id, prev, next)` is rewritten to `3 = ANY('{id, prev, next}')` internally. EXPLAIN ANALYZE reveals it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, interestingly, I was going to mention the same thing, but in my case (using 9.3.1) the EXPLAIN ANALYZE showed `Filter: ((3 = x.id) OR (3 = x.prev) OR (3 = x.next))` rather than the array version. Perhaps the array version is what occurs when you have an `IN()` list of values, not colums? I know I've seen what you describe in query plans before, so you are correct.

Comment: @bma: Well, ultimately either of these expressions is resolved to a list of ORed expressions. Maybe, the 9.3.1 planner goes one step further in this process. I didn't retest with the latest version.

Comment: Wow the `3 in (id, prev, next)` blows my mind, I wish I knew about that before :)